# SyntaxError: invalid syntax(Mapreduce+python)

Tags: python-2.7, mapreduce, syntax-error

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

when i tried to execute the above code am getting syntax error please find the screenprint and help me out on this regard.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smLoe.jpg

Comment: You're missing the : at the end of the line in your screenshot.

Comment: attached screenshot is an error message displayed , but take a look at mapper code  and let me know in case of modification@WanderNauta